# Types.isSameType returns true for two different type elements

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

```
TypeMirror listType = elementUtils.getTypeElement("java.util.List").asType();
TypeMirror thisType = typeUtils.asElement(element.asType()).asType();
boolean isSame = typeUtils.isSameType(listType, thisType);
```

Whlile `listType = java.util.List<E>` and `thisType = User` but still I get `isSame = true`.

What's going on here?

Comment: You need to show a [more complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, what is `element`? What is the significance of `typeUtils.asElement(element.asType()).asType()`? (Why not just `element.asType()`?)